# Loading asc.gz file into R

Tags: r, ascii, raster, terra

I have several 'asc.gz' files that i want to load in R using the terra package and create a raster stack out of it. Here is my code:

## read all ascii files and convert them into a raster stack

```
for (i in 1:length(filenames)){
  if (i == 1){
# for the first run define our final raster file ...
    current_ascii <- as.matrix(read.table(gzfile(filenames[i])))
# remove the raster in case it already exists to avoid duplicate entries
    rm(my_raster)
    my_raster <- rast(current_ascii)
  } else {
# ... and fill it with each additional run with another layer
    current_ascii <- as.matrix(read.table(gzfile(filenames[i])))
    current_raster <- rast(current_ascii)
    add(my_raster) <- current_raster
# Delete all variables except for the raster stack "my_raster"
    rm(i, current_ascii, current_raster)
  }
}
```

Unfortunatly, there seems to be some issues with reading the coordinates, because when I try to plot the single files it looks weirdUnfortunatly, there seems to be some issues with reading the coordinates, because when I try to plot the single files it looks weird

Comment: What's the output of `terra::rast(gzfile(filenames[1]))`?

Answer (score 0):

If these are gzipped Arc-ASCII files you might be able to read them all in one step like this:

```
x <- rast(paste0("/vsigzip/", filenames))
```

The looping approach is not great either. If you had to do something like that (which I doubt), you could instead

```
rr <- lapply(filenames, 
           function(f) { #read(f) })
              
rr <- rast(rr)
```